# Force a client to call a method on the service?

Tags: wcf, service

I'm wondering if there's any way to force a client to call a specific method on a duplex WCF service.  My situation is this, my service implementation is going to keep a collection of subscribers.  The problem with this approach is, what if the client doesn't call Subscribe()?  I was thinking that in my client interface, I'd have a method called Subscribe, but that doesn't get me anywhere since the code to actually call the service can still be left out of the implementation.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't allow your client to do anything else without calling the `Subscribe` method. If your service is useful, then the client will need to call `Subscribe` in order to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplex WCF service uses WCF session so you can mark your Subscribe method with:

```
[OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
void Subscribe();
```

All other methods will have `IsInitiating=false` and because of that `Subscribe` method will have to be the first method called to start a new session. You can also have special method with `IsTerminating=true` to close the session.

Comment: Would this approach still work if I have my service's InstanceContextMode = Single?

Comment: @Ryan: That is a good question. I'm not sure but I believe that this is related to session not to instancing but you will have to try it. Session exists even if you use `InstanceContextMode=Single`.

Comment: The reason I ask is that on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) for Sessions, it states that when the server accepts a client session, "All calls between a WCF client object are handled by the same service instance."  I wasn't sure how this affected me since I only had one instance to begin with.

Comment: @Ryan: That is true in per session instancing but sessions still exists with single instancing. The service instance is shared by all sessions.